# Rails, mutiple create methods in one controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I need to have two (or maybe even more) different create (and update) methods in one controller. I already have views displaying the forms, so I basicaly only need to tell the submit which method to call in the controller. Is that possible? If so, how? Or can I only have one create method and have that method do different things depending on which view called the method?

Thanks

Comment: You could change the behaviour of create with params passed to it?

Comment: Yes, I have given that some thougt too. My problem is, that I kind of need to misuse an update as an insert. So one call would come from a new form, the other from an edit form. My "update" still needs to keep the old record in the table. Also working with a legacy database isnt making matters simpler...

Comment: Surely the old records should be kept in a separate table? Anyway, you can create records in your update action, there's nothing to stop you doing that. The params method would work unless I'm missing something. If you insist on the "bt view" method, you could possibly use the referer link?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that this sounds like a really terrible idea, it's possible. You will need to add some more routes that will match the new actions in your controller. You won't be able to call them 'create' and 'update' because method names must be unique within the same class.

Having said that, I really beg you to rethink your approach. REST, as described in the [Rails Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), by far the standard for building Rails applications. If you're not familiar with it, I would recommend stopping where you are and reading up on it. Your application will be much easier to build and maintain, and you won't waste time asking structural questions. If you are familiar with it and are choosing to ignore it, then I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

> rails g scaffold_controller 'controller_name'

or if spastic method you can use this:

> rails generate controller 'controller_name' add new

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have an object `Book`. You can change values of Book in any method inside of your `books_controller.rb` as long as that method has access to `@book.id`.

```
def crazy_create_method
  book.create (book_params)
  book.save
end
```

That being said, try to stick to the default new/create methods and if you need to get weird later on it's always easy to call the code belong in whatever method you need. Rails bakes a lot of out of the box functionality into the default REST actions.

```
book.title = my_title  
book.save
```